# Are there any traceroute programs that do not rely on ICMP echo requests?

Tags: udp, icmp, traceroute

Are there any traceroute programs that do not rely on ICMP echo requests?

Please list any programs if you know of them, or ways to achieve a traceroute without ICMP echo requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `traceroute` itself.

By default most UNIX `traceroute` implementations (e.g. Linux, OSX) will not use ICMP echo requests. They use UDP packets to an unlikely port.

(However, Windows `tracert` will use ICMP echo requests and as far as I know there is no option to change that.)

UNIX based `traceroute` usually allows the user to select alternative methods including ICMP echo requests, TCP and more. The options to select these depend on your `traceroute` implementation. For example on Linux you would do

```
traceroute -T
```

to do a TCP based traceroute, while on OSX it would be

```
traceroute -P TCP
```

However, all `traceroute` implementations rely on the reception of ICMP TIME_EXCEEDED messages.

Comment: The default traceroute implementation is OS-specific. Windows, by default uses ICMP.

Comment: Thanks, added this to the answer.